# Accessing Ubuntu Server 10.04 that is installed in Ubuntu Desktop 10.04 using VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-10.04

I've installed Ubuntu Server 10.04 in Ubuntu Desktop 10.04 using Oracle's VirtualBox successfully.

I've also configured the IP address of the server during the installation process.

But I am unable to access the server via SSH in my Ubuntu Desktop 10.04.

How do I access the server via SSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Does ping your_server_ip_address work?
2. What is the output of

   ```
   ssh -v root@your_server_ip_address
   ```
3. Is the ubuntu firewall enabled on the server?
4. Is ssh root access enabled on the server?
5. Does the ssh access work with a non-root user?

Comment: Hello, 1) Pinging to my ip address works. 2) the output of ssh -v root@my_server_ip is OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu5, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
3) i've tried ssh -v non-root@my_server_ip and got the same results as 2. 4) No, it is not enables. 5) SSH doesnt work with non root user.

Comment: Have you set something in /etc/hosts.deny ? Is perhaps AllowUsers being used in /etc/ssh/sshd_config ? Is "PermitRootLogin yes" in  /etc/ssh/sshd_config ?